Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard, incompatible version (AGP 8.2.0) AGP 8.1.2
I've downloaded the Kotlin Multiplatform project provided by the JetBrains Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard. Upon opening the project in Android Studio and completing the synchronization process, I encountered this error:
"The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 8.2.0) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 8.1.2."
I can't find any Gradle file where I can change this version.
It seems you've tried to add the line in the build.gradle.kts file to change the version but it didn't work.

You need to either upgrade Android Studio or downgrade the AGP version (com.android.application) in gradle.
Look at the compatibility matrix to find matching versions.

Thank you, I updated the version of Android Studio to the Iguana version and it worked.

@Alvaro: If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to the both of us.
